# Ergodic Theory exercise book

Tags: book-recommendation, ergodic-theory

There are references on Ergodic Theory in this website but my question is about solving problems not the text. I have the course Ergodic Theory taught from Walter's Ergodic Theory book but this book has no exercises in it so I was wondering if there is a book that covers same topics but has solved exercises in it? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: How about https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-15915-3 ?